# Using class members in a static function

Tags: c++

I've got a problem. Using VS2010.

```
    class B { }; class C { };

    class A {
         static B b;
         C c;
    public:
         static int foo();
    };
```

When I try to use **c** in foo I receive an error that I can't use non-static members in a static function. When I try to use **b** in foo I receive the following: 
unresolved external symbol "private:static class B A::b"
What should I do?

Comment: have you try static C c; instead of C c

Answer (score 7):

That's two distinct questions.  With regards to the first, in
order to use `c`, you need an instance; `c` doesn't exist except
in an instance.  If you pass a reference to an `A` to your
static function, you can access the `c` in that object.  With
regards to the second: the declaration of a static data member is
just that: a declaration.  You need a definition somewhere:

```
B A::b;
```

in a (single) source file.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. You meant define only once.

Answer (score 4):

Non-`static` members are associated with *particular instances* of a class, whereas `static` functions aren't associated with any particular instance.  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to work with non-`static` members in a `static` function: which instance would you be referring to?  As to what you should do, I don't know.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

The message about "unresolved external symbol" is probably because you have *declared* `b`. but you haven't *defined* it; you need to put `B A::b;` somewhere *outside* the class declaration, normally in one of your source files (don't put it in a header file).

Comment: I am trying to make an OOP wrapping over Win32API. I have a class named Handler with static BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); and i need to acces class members in that function.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I've put B A::b in a source file and that worked!